# Angular ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just learning angular.js here is my first 'hello world' script.  I am trying to use ng-include to include a navbar from local file /templates/nav.html.  I am following a tutorial and cant figure out why its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <header ng-include src="'templates/nav.html'">
    </header>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <section>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

this is my js/app.js file:

```
angular
.module('app', [
'ui.router'
]);
```

templates/nav.html is simply the default bootstrap navbar.  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: why you using angular version `1.0.8`, you can use the latest versions.

Comment: working http://plnkr.co/edit/eroL6G043EFsCpeQUMph?p=preview

Comment: I agree with K. Toress, why are you using such an old version ?

Comment: Hey sorry about that i must have grabbed the wrong cdn.  I grabbed the latest version and correct the syntax.. it still seems to be not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your js/app.js file as a script - right now there's no angular app being instantiated.

Add this as the last script to be included:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then I don't see what the problem is, this should work: Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RcN02Qilrjj6fgPlN8K9?p=preview

Comment: do i need to use a specific file structure? i have a css, images, js, templates, and index.html

Comment: Is anything printed in your browser's console output?

Comment: yes actually, angular is not defined, Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined, and ERR_file not found

Comment: Try including jquery before angular (see here for details): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84284/discussion-between-mofojed-and-vault-dweller).

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
    <div ng-include="'templates/nav.html'"></div>
```

And put the header tag inside your nav.html.